# Upload local files to docker container

Tags: docker

There is the following code In my Dockerfile :

```
ENV GOVERS 073fc578434b

RUN cd /usr/local && curl -O http://go.googlecode.com/archive/$GOVERS.zip
RUN cd /usr/local && unzip -q $GOVERS.zip
```

the above code downloads the zip file to the `/usr/local` directory and all is ok. But now i do not want to download the zip file, I want to get the zip file from my local PC to the `/usr/local` at the docker container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let say the zip file is named `test.zip` and is located in the same directory as your Dockerfile, then you can make use of the [COPY](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#copy) instruction in your dockerfile. You will then have:

```
COPY test.zip /usr/local/
RUN cd /usr/local && unzip -q test.zip
```

Furthermore you can use the [ADD](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add) instruction instead of `COPY` to also uncompress the zip file and you won't need to RUN the unzip command:

```
ADD test.zip /usr/local/
```

Comment: i used ADD go /usr/local/   go is a uncompress folder,but it give me bash: line 0: cd: /usr/local/go/src: No such file or directory but i have  the src folder  is located at the go which 
 in the same directory as your Dockerfile

Comment: Make sure to read the [documentation](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add) for the `ADD` instruction. It behaves differently depending on if `<src>` and/or `<dest>` is a directory or file

Comment: i have read it,<src> and <dest> all are directory,so i used ADD go /usr/local/ but it give me No such file or directory

Comment: in that case use `COPY go /usr/local/go`

Comment: you can answer my the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504846/copy-directory-to-other-directory-at-docker-using-add-command  i will accept

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that I am starting to like is using volumes and runtime commands. I don't like to have to rebuild the image if I change something incidental.

So I create a volume in the docker file to transfer stuff back and forth:
In Docker file:

```
RUN mkdir -p /someplace/dropbox
....
CMD ..... ; $POST_START ; tail -f /var/log/messages
```

on host:

```
mkdir /dropbox && cp ~/Downloads/fap.zip /dropbox \
 docker run -v /dropbox:/someplace/dropbox  \
   -e POST_START="cp /someplace/dropbox/fap.zip /someplace-else; cd /someplace-else;unzip fap.zip" ..... <image>
```