# Copy directory to another directory using ADD command

Tags: docker

I have read http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add however I met a problem. I want to copy the local directory `go` to docker `/user/local/`

I tried:

```
ADD go /usr/local/
```

and:

```
ADD /go/ /usr/local/
```

also:

```
RUN chmod 0755 /usr/local/go/src/make.bash
```

However, I see the following error message:

```
/usr/local/go/src/make.bash: No such file or directory
```

but the local `go` directory does contain `make.bash`.

Answer (score 1167, accepted):

```
ADD go /usr/local/
```

will copy the **[contents](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)** of your local `go` directory into the `/usr/local/` directory of your docker image.

To copy the `go` directory itself in `/usr/local/` use:

```
ADD go /usr/local/go
```

or

```
COPY go /usr/local/go
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the multiple source version of ADD, and so I can't specify the target directory name for the destination. Is there a way to do what the OP asked in a multi-src format (i.e. without creating an `ADD` layer for each source directory)?

Comment: maybe start a new question with an example of what you tried, what you expected and what you got

Comment: In docker 1.0.1, the add command will not work though relative paths up (and out) of your current directory, and will also not resolve symlinks.

Comment: I just want to add a sidenote to this by saying that `$HOME` or `~` or any other shell variable will not work. I'm saying this because I spent good amount trying to figure this out than I'd like to admit even though it's glaringly obvious to most.

Comment: COPY go /usr/local/go doesn't work for me.  Does not copy.

Comment: Don't think this works because /usr/local/ is an absolute path.

Comment: This is really quite a confusing matter. Why can't `COPY` simply behave like `cp`? Instead there needs to be an extra police how it works.

Comment: .dockerignore file can hide a directory and COPY or ADD will not work for listed items

Comment: it appears to try copying from a staged directory instead of the actual host. So `/usr/local/go` is actually `/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builderasdfasdf/user/local/go`

Comment: In my case my `.dockerignore` had a line with `*` in it, causing this command to fail for me.

Comment: So, one would not need to add a flag like `-r` to the `COPY` command? Not sure if this flag exists for COPY; I just know that it exists for the regular `cp` command.

Comment: Suppose I wish to add a directory (not just contents) and another file to destination then can I do it in one command?

Answer (score 132):

Indeed `ADD go /usr/local/` will add **content** of `go` folder and not the folder itself, you can use Thomasleveil solution or if that did not work for some reason you can change `WORKDIR` to `/usr/local/` then add your directory to it like:

```
WORKDIR /usr/local/
COPY go go/
```

or

```
WORKDIR /usr/local/go
COPY go ./
```

**BUT** if you want to add **multiple** folders, it will be annoying to add them like that, the only solution for now as I see it from my current issue is using `COPY . .` and exclude all unwanted directories and files in `.dockerignore`, let's say I got folders and files:

```
- src 
- tmp 
- dist 
- assets 
- go 
- justforfun 
- node_modules 
- scripts 
- .dockerignore 
- Dockerfile 
- headache.lock 
- package.json
```

and I want to add `src assets package.json justforfun go` so:

in Dockerfile:

```
FROM galaxy:latest

WORKDIR /usr/local/
COPY . .
```

in .dockerignore file:

```
node_modules
headache.lock
tmp
dist
```

In this way, you ignore `node_modules headache.lock tmp dist` so they will not be added!

**Second approach:** Or for more fun (or you like to confuse more people make them suffer as well :P) can be:

```
*
!src 
!assets 
!go 
!justforfun 
!scripts 
!package.json
```

In this way you ignore everything, but exclude what you want to be copied or added only from the "ignore list".

It is a late answer but adding more ways to do the same covers even more cases.

Comment: This answer is much more clear, and actually works. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This approach can copy unwanted files and directories on docker images unawares, if forgot updating files or directories which newly added on `.dockerignore`.

Comment: @InsungPark you can ignore everything and exclude what you want to be added, did you see my second approach?

Comment: @Al-Mothafar Oh, I didn't check your last approach, I think it will work well and until now it's maybe only way to keep single layer on copying multiple directory, even a little bit tricky. 
Thank you for notifying me.

Answer (score 34):

You can use COPY. You need to specify the directory explicitly. It won't be created by itself

```
COPY go /usr/local/go
```

Reference: [Docker CP reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

Answer (score 17):

As the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) state:

> The directory itself is not copied, just its contents.

The trick is to concat in the `<dest>` path also the folder name, like this:

```
COPY src ./src
```

Even if ./src does not exist in the container yet, the command COPY internally creates it and copies the content of src into the new folder (which is ./src).

Answer (score -3):

Years late, but I had this issue because my folder had a . in it.  When I removed it, the error was gone

Answer (score -5):

This can help if you want to add all files to a specified location

#ADD XML SUITE files
ADD src/test/resources/xmls/*                   /usr/share/tag/