# Docker add fails with no such file or directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a docker file that I have used many many times to build an image. But now when I try and build it fails with:

```
Step 18/25 : ADD mysql /var/lib/mysql
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder258868311/mysql: no such file or directory
```

The mysql dir does exist locally and it is readable. What could have changed that is now causing this? How can I debug the problem?

Comment: Are you running `docker build` from the right directory (or with the correct path specified)?

Comment: Yes I am running the build from the dir that contains the mysql dir and I am running it with `docker build -t myImage:local -f Dockerfile .`

Comment: why u need -f flag if dockerfile is in current direcotry

Comment: Maybe I don't, but that's how I've always run the build command. But that is not the cause of the error I am getting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504846/copy-directory-to-other-directory-at-docker-using-add-command

Comment: How does that answer my question? I want to copy the entire local mysql dir to /var/lib/mysql inside the container. So isn't `ADD mysql /var/lib/mysql` the correct syntax for that?

Answer (score 0):

It could be expecting a single file because the destination does not end with a trailing slash:

> If  does not end with a trailing slash, it will be considered a regular file and the contents of  will be written at .
>   [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add)

Try `ADD mysql /var/lib/mysql/` (and make sure there is no .dockerignore with mysql in it!)

Comment: Nope that did not help. And I do not have a . dockerignore file.